# android AAPT loses some resources

Tags: android, resources, flags, aapt

My app imports android.support.v7.appcompat. Both my app and this android jar have resource file colors.xml and strings.xml. My app works well if I use Android Studio 1.5 to build it. But when I tried to use Android.mk to build it together with the rest of my system, the app just crashes every time. It comes down to the following line that returns 0 length of fields instead of many colors that are defined in resource files.

```
    Field[] fields = R.color.class.getFields();
```

I used java decompiler to compare two apk files built by android studio and Android.mk. The good one has R.color class in both android.support.v7.appcompat and my own resource R.class. The bad one has an empty color class. and I saw R.java in the intermediate file folder still has all colors but it is lost in apk. 
    //good
    public static final class color
    {
        public static final int abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_dark = 2131624259;
      .....
    }
    // bad:
    public static final class color {}

At first I guess that I missed a flag or option in Android.mk that I copied from the other app. But I found that other android apps that are built by Android.mk don't have color resource either. They are OK because they don't use this color resource. so what's the difference between Android Studio and Android.mk? How can I fix it?

My system is android 5.1.1. 
My Android.mk looks like this. the commented out lines show that I tried these options and didn't work.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#Include res dir from libraries
#appcompat_dir := prebuilts/sdk/current/support/v7/appcompat
#appcompat_dir := frameworks/support/v7/appcompat
#appcompat_dir := ../../../../../../../../../android-sdk-linux/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res
appcompat_dir := 
res_dirs := res libs/v7/appcompat/res

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := android-support-v7-appcompat
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += android-support-v4

$(warning LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES is '$(LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES)')

$(warning TARGET_BUILD_APPS is '$(TARGET_BUILD_APPS)')
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, java)

LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(addprefix $(LOCAL_PATH)/, $(res_dirs))
#LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR += $(appcompat_dir)/res

$(warning LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR is '$(LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR)')

LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := --auto-add-overlay
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS += --extra-packages android.support.v7.appcompat

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MyApp

LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAG_FILES := proguard.flags 

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

#include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := externalappcompatv7:libs/v7/appcompat/libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar
#include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)

#include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

Comment: I eventually modified the third party java library to avoid iterating all colors in resource. Therefore, avoid the crash.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually modified the third party java library that I used to avoid iterating all colors in the resource. Therefore, avoid the crash.